# Error type unexpectedly involved in table query construction

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to build a table with a query expression as mentioned in [create tables with query](https://ballerina.io/learn/distinctive-language-features/data/#create-tables-with-query) but I keep running into issue:

```
ERROR incompatible types: expected 'table<Foo> key(a)', found '(table<Foo> key(a)|error)'
```

It's easy to work around e.g.:

```
table<Foo> key(a)|error x = ...
```

or

```
check table key(a) ...
```

But what bothers me here is that I fail to find any explanation from the documentation why an error is involved here when in list comprehension it's not as the following compiles and runs just fine:

```
Foo[] x = from int i in 0...9 select {a:i, b:0};
```

The complete example:

```
$ cat issue.bal 
import ballerina/io;

type Foo record {|
    readonly int a;
    int b;
|};

public function main() {
    table<Foo> key(a) x = 
        table key(a)
        from int i in 0...9
        select {a:i, b:0}
    ;

    io:println(x);
}
```

```
$ bal run issue.bal
Compiling source
    issue.bal
ERROR [issue.bal:(10:9,12:31)] incompatible types: expected 'table<Foo> key(a)', found '(table<Foo> key(a)|error)'
error: compilation contains errors
```

I'm using:

```
$ bal version
Ballerina 2201.1.0 (Swan Lake Update 1)
Language specification 2022R2
Update Tool 1.3.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug that was tracked with https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/36686 and fixed. The fix will be made available with the 2201.2.0 release, which will be released soon.

Comment: Looking at the issue I see `on conflict` clause. Is that documented somewhere ?

Comment: Please refer to https://ballerina.io/why-ballerina/data-oriented/#on-conflict-clause which explains its usage with an example.

Here's the language specification reference
https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/2022R1/#section_6.35.8